# How transform pixel array to png with PNGJS SYNC

Tags: javascript, node.js, pngjs

I'm doing it like this and it works fine

```
const png = new PNG({
  width: 2048,
  height: 2048,
  filterType: 4,
});
png.data = mydata;

png.pack().pipe(fs.createWriteStream("image.png"));
```

but it uses stream and I need it to be sync

I tried the following without success

```
const png = PNG.sync.read(undefined, {
    width: 2048,
    height: 2048,
    filterType: 4,
  });
  png.data = mydata;

  fs.writeFileSync("image.png", PNG.sync.write(png));
```